difference between u8"" and common string "" in c++ string
I wrote the code below, and saved my source file as UTF-8:
std::string utf8_string = u8"你好，世界";
std::string simple_string = "你好，世界";
std::cout << utf8_string.size()<<":" << utf8_string << std::endl;
std::cout << simple_string.size()<<":"<<simple_string << std::endl;

When execute the code, it showed information below:
15:浣犲ソ锛屼笘鐣
10:你好，世界

I read some tutorial, it says that "你好，世界" will be encoded as your source file encoding, so it is UTF-8 as the source file is saved. But why this get different answer?

Is the u8 string literal necessary in C++11 and also How are u8-literals supposed to work?

tldr of the dupe: u8 means that the literal is always UTF-8 while the one without it doesn't.

"[I] saved my source file as UTF-8" - did you tell that to your compiler so it parses the file correctly? Ie, did you pass a flag to the compiler setting the source encoding to UTF-8? Or save the file with a leading UTF-8 BOM?
